Adjusting the height of an equation in Microsoft Word
I've inserted an equation in Microsoft Word, but part of it it is not shown fully:

it should be(as rendered in LaTeX:

my question: what can be done to make Microsoft Word renders the equaion correctly?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

In Word, I changed the spacing between paragraphs from 1.0 to 1.5, and now the equation renders correctly.
